# Problems with making clickable linkt to web in beamer

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I have (on windows with latest miktex) a beamer presentation where I want to make a clickable web link, twice. It works in one case, not in the other:

This case works as expected:

```
\href{http://forskning.no/skog-matematikk-barn-og-ungdom-pedagogiske-fag-skole-og-utdanning/2012/07/laer-matematikk-av-skogen}{\beamergotobutton{Lær
    i skogen}}
```

This one makes a button, but clicking it has no effect (and, yes, the link within is correct):

```
\href{villemo.com/blog/?p=2858}{\beamergotobutton{Utematte---Emma}}
```

Any ideas what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try adding `http://`. That solved it on my computer...

```
\href{http://villemo.com/blog/?p=2858}{\beamergotobutton{Utematte---Emma}}
```